# java 8 - Passing a function through bindings

Tags: java, java-8, nashorn

When calling a java function within JS it is not possible to work in different scopes (global/engine).

```
engine.eval("function proxy(a){return Java.type('Foo').bar(a);}",engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE));
engine.eval("function withoutProxy(){return Java.type('Foo').bar(m);}",engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE));
engine.eval("function withProxy(){return proxy(m);}", engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE));
```

(Where `m` is a JS function declared in the engine scope)

Invoking `withoutProxy` works fine. But `withProxy` throws

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror to java.util.function.Function
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleImpl.newClassCastException(MethodHandleImpl.java:361)
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleImpl.castReference(MethodHandleImpl.java:356)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$7$17A$\^eval\_.proxy(<eval>:1)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:639)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror.call(ScriptObjectMirror.java:117)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$6$20$\^eval\_.withProxy(<eval>:1)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:637)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:494)
at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:393)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror.callMember(ScriptObjectMirror.java:199)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:383)
at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.invokeFunction(NashornScriptEngine.java:190)
```

(the stacktrace is with using 1.8.0_102-ea. Same exception with jdk1.8.0_05 and jdk1.8.0_73.)

So: Did I do something wrong, is it intended or a bug?

([Gist of my test class](https://gist.github.com/MisterErwin/afb02ed9ab7f3e3ce39af3e82f10c3f0))

Comment: I don't have any error with JDK 1.8.0_51. This could have been a fixed bug?

Comment: In the oracle/java bugtracker it says that something similar (just changing bindings) was fixed post 8u40 (so 8u60 and above).
But afaik 1.8.0_102-ea is never than 1.8.0_51.

Comment: I have also tested it on a different machine. (Ubuntu with java 1.8.0_91). Same error. (To be surer that it is now caused my some sort of misconfiguration)

Comment: This is new issue related to working with different scope, We at Oracle evaluating this issue and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved now with http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8162839 in JDK 9-ea b 147 which can be downloaded from https://jdk9.java.net/download/

Comment: The most important part of the answer is that the issue is resolved (in ea builds). So I just went ahead and accepted it.